# CSS issue: Footer overlapping with above content

Tags: css, overlap

Please take a look here http://sources.freehosting.bg/1st-level.html

The footer overlaps the above content when the page gets "minimized" in the window. I have tried to resolve this for hours but with no luck.

Maximized: http://store.picbg.net/pubpic/99/2A/db640a6f9063992a.PNG
Minimized: http://store.picbg.net/pubpic/E4/96/2c1e86018b7be496.PNG

The floats are cleared, I have no idea what might be causing this. Please help me solve it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `setHeights` is causing the problem, it is setting the heights' of `#content` and main `.main` smaller than their content so it overflows, if you take out the `-20` it seems to work, but why set the heights any way as it would expand with its content.

```
function setHeights() {
    var newHeight=$(document).height() - 290;
    $('#content').height(newHeight);
    $('.main').height(newHeight/*-20*/);
}
```

Comment: It seems that was causing it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `margin-top: -30px` from `#footer` in your CSS.

Comment: I just removed it. The issue persists. It overlaps with more than 30px.

Comment: Are you sure you removed it and re-uploaded your CSS? I'm using Chrome and removing the `margin-top` solves the problem.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Clear your cache and you will see. Here is how I see it now: http://store.picbg.net/pubpic/6B/40/97b62cca98916b40.PNG